# Visio 2010 opens web link read only on some PCs...other open Read Write

Tags: webdav, visio, ithit-webdav-server

We are using the itHit Server and Ajax WebDAV Library to edit documents with our web application.  We have two client PCs. Both have the same OS (W7 sp1 64bit) and Visio 2010 (14.0.7145.5000 32-bit).  One has IE9 and the other has IE11.  The IE9 PC opens the Visio document read-only after prompting for user credentials.  The IE11 PC open the Visio document read-write after prompting for the user credentials.  We noticed in Fiddler that the IE9 log never gets to the Lock command but the IE11 does.  The IE11 log shows a number of commands (options/propfind/head) that are not in the IE9 log.

What could be causing this?  Since Visio has started (and prompts for the user credentials), IE should not be involved but that is a difference in the two PCs

Answer (score 1):

I set HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\WebClient\Parameters\BasicAuthLevel=dword:00000002 and both PCs that did not work now opened the document RW and allowed to save back to the server…
see: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2123563?wa=wsignin1.0

Answer (score 0):

Possibly MS Visio has cached information about the previous unsuccessful WebDAV connection somewhere. Please try the following on the computer where you have this issue:

1. Unmount WebDAV connections executing following console command:

   net use * /DELETE

   This will unmount all network connections including WebDAV. With 'net use' command you can also list connections first and unmount only specific WebDAV connections if you do not want to unmount all connections.
2. Delete cached credentials if any. You can do this executing the following command:

   rundll32.exe keymgr.dll, KRShowKeyMgr
3. Clear MS Office WebDAV connections cache. It is stored under the key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\\Common\Internet\Server Cache\
   To clear cache just delete all keys under this key.

Also make sure you have all Windows and Visio updates installed.

Comment: the Net Use did not delete any...the keymgr.dll did not have any cached credentials and I delete three keys below the Office\14.0\...Server Cache...Visio still opens as Read-only...

Comment: The server is running IIS7.5 (2008r2).  I did find a server that is IIS6.0 (2003) that opens the Visio document RW (and it does not prompt for user credentials when opening the file) on the same PC that is opening it RO.

Comment: The difference is that the 2003 is using Forms Authentication mode (with anonymous authentication enabled) and the 2008r2 is using Windows Authentication mode (with Basic authentication enabled)...Neither are using SSL..

Comment: I changed the W2003 server from Form back to Windows Authentication.  Turned off Anonymous and turned on Basic...Visio document opened as read-only...switched back...document opened as read-write.

Comment: I changed the W2008r2 server to use Forms authentication and the document opened as RW...I could save the document on the IE11 PC and not the IE9 PC.  Both open as RO using Windows authentication